# Installing OpenVpn on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to install OpenVpn on Ubuntu 15.10 and running into issues. Here are the instructions from (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN):
    Step 3:

```
Setup the CA and create the first server certificate
cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/ ## move to the easy-rsa directory
sudo chown -R root:admin .  ## make this directory writable by the system administrators
sudo chmod g+w . ## make this directory writable by the system administrators
```

Here is the error that I am receiving:

```
root@example:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa# chown -R root:admin .
chown: invalid group: ‘root:admin’
```

I could I guess create a group called Admin but I don't want to be experimenting here. I am somewhat new to Linux. What is the updated best practice for "Setup the CA and create the first server certificate"?

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: The `admin` group has been replaced buy the `sudo` group some years back. Try using `root:sudo` instead.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Is there a way for me to "file a bug report" on the official Ubuntu documentation? If it were changed years back, why hasnt this documentation been updated?

Comment: @PeterS, sadly, there is a LOT of Ubuntu documentation that is out of date. As far as I could find, the team that keeps the documentation updated is a group of about 57 people.

Comment: @SuperSluether Do they have a mechanism for "defect" reporting? if so, I would love to log each defect that I find, and maybe even do some correcting of the docs.

Comment: @PeterS This looks like a good place to start: https://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/documentation/

Comment: @PeterS You may want to contact the author of the guide rather then file bug reports. I've tried editing that page, but found no apparent way of doing so.

Comment: This link leads to an awesome tutorial. I used it to set up openvpn with no problem at all. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I raised a bug report bug report for this issue and the documentation has now been updated:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1532959

Comment: @MikeWahever: If you register on Launchpad and sign the Ubuntu code of conduct, you can change the documentation yourself... (15Krep here carries *some weight*) **;-)**

Comment: @DavidFoerster I second that!!

Comment: @DavidFoerster All done! I've actually tried editing that page right away, but couldn't get the edit window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root:sudo` should be used instead.

The admin group has been replaced by the sudo group some years back (it must have [started with Precise in 2012](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#PrecisePangolin.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure.Common_Infrastructure)).

> Up until Ubuntu 11.10, administrator access using the sudo tool was granted via the "admin" Unix group. In Ubuntu 12.04, administrator access will be granted via the "sudo" group. This makes Ubuntu more consistent with the upstream implementation and Debian. For compatibility purposes, the "admin" group will continue to provide sudo/administrator access in 12.04.